# R programming - Set the end of a timeframe to today

Tags: r, datetime

This is a very simple question, so hopefully it is easy to answer.  Here is some sample data:

```
a <- seq(as.Date("2016-10-10"), as.Date("2016-11-22"), by = "day")
data.table(a)
```

I am trying to set a timeframe in R so that the end date is today.  I have code that works:

```
b <- a[a%between% c("2016-10-20", "2016-11-21")]
```

I tried to use `Sys.Date()`, and it doesn't work, and I have no idea why:

```
gamesplayed <- gamesplayed[Date %between% c("2016-10-20", Sys.Date())]
```

I get the error `Error in charToDate(x) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format` which I googled and it seems like the answers are related to date format errors, and I can't figure out why that would be my error.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have everything in a consistent format, either a `Date` object or a `character` string. E.g.:

```
a[a %between% c(as.Date("2016-10-20"), Sys.Date())]
# [1] "2016-10-20" "2016-10-21" "2016-10-22" "2016-10-23" "2016-10-24"
# ...
#[31] "2016-11-19" "2016-11-20" "2016-11-21" "2016-11-22"
```

It would be preferable to always explicitly compare `Date` to `Date` when dealing with, well, dates. Even though R can handle comparing `Date` to `character` on occasions, which is why your original code worked when specifying the range of `%between%` as both `character` objects.

```
Sys.Date() == "2016-11-23"
#[1] TRUE
Sys.Date() == as.Date("2016-11-23")
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Spot on. Using proper types is key, and makes even working with dates possible.